# Is marking and labelling topo points possible?

Tags: modeling, text-object

I have a topo surface created by using a a heightmap as displacment modifier which does a nice job as below. My question part A is can I add a marker (say like the circle, or it could be just a dot) to the surface of the topo that will remain attached even as I change the strength or position of the topo surface? Second, and more ambitiously, would be an attempt to emulate Sketchup by having a label and arrow where the arrow would follow the point on the topo. My goal is to create block diagram of terrains where the terrain can be viewed from different angles but the labels will remain facing the viewer. I am not experienced in Blender and will be happy for a general suggestion for developing this technique.

[image]

Comment: When you say 'change the position'.. do you mean translate the entire mesh, or change the position of the texture relative to a fixed mesh? (i.e. slide the texture through a mesh which is just there to display heights?)

Answer (score 2):

First, enter edit mode on your surface object, select the point you want to and assign them to a new vertex group via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

Create your Circle object. Give him a [Child Of constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/child_of.html), set your topo as the target, and specify the vertex group you just created as well.
You can also add a [Track To constraint](https://easyblend.org/html/rigging/constraints/tracking/track_to.html), with your camera as target, "To" on Z and "Up" as Y, so that your circle always faces your camera.

For the arrow, I think it should do with the [Hook Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html). I never use this one so I'm guessing in the dark here, Bu I guess you need to create a vertex group with the vertices you need to stick on the circle, then add the hook modifier on the arrow object, set the circle as target and specify your point's vertex group.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like your captions to be in screen space, you could take the following approach.

**Place and parent targets**

For each location

- Select a corresponding vertex on the terrain mesh
- Place the cursor there
- Create a target empty on the vertex
- In object mode, Shift-select the landscape ( both selected, terrain active), switch to Edit Mode, and with the vertex still selected, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> parent the Empty to it.

**Create and parent label objects**

- Place the camera looking down Z at the terrain, a sensible distance from it, to make a shot. You need to leave space between the camera and the terrain to make room for the labels, which will be at a fixed distance from the camera
- Create the labels reasonably close to the camera, locate them over the targets in the camera view.
- Having placed and sized the labels, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> apply any transforms you have made in Object Mode.
- Place all the origins of the labels at the camera ( <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> Cursor to camera, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> origin to cursor)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> Parent the labels to the camera.

**Constrain the labels**

- Give each label a Damped Track constraint, with the corresponding target Empty as its target. (The axis will probably be -Z)

Now the labels should follow the targets, when viewed through the camera

[image]

The change in size of the caption at the end of this shot is the result of zooming the camera (changing it focal length)

[image]